# Xcode debugger console not printing strings without NSString:stringWithFormat

Tags: xcode, debugging, console

Recently, maybe with XCode 7.x, the debug console has been less than helpful at printing out certain objects, even just strings.  Usually it just doesn't print anything, yet the object is not null, not empty, and after some pushing it will finally print it.  Like this example below of a string I use.  Why do I have to encapsulate it in stringWithFormat to get it to print?    There area lot of NSString subclasses that seem to be in use coming from different sources.

```
(lldb) po someVar

(lldb) po someVar == nil
false

(lldb) po [someVar class]
__NSCFString

(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",someVar]
My string value

(lldb)
```